# CeSetUserNotificationEx with named event and CNT_TIME fails under services.exe

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-services, windows-ce, notifications

I have a service application, a simple dll running under services.exe. I can attach the VS debugger to services.exe, activate the service application dll and then single step it in the debugger without any problem.

Now, I try to use CeSetUserNotificationEx to be notified at a certain time in the future. I use the CNT_TIME trigger type with the named event naming scheme. When doing this under services.exe, the event is never signaled by the notification subsystem when the time occurs.

If I run the dll under a separate exe that just loads the xxx_Init function (and other xxx_...) and calls it, then the exact same code will generate a signaled event when the time occurs.

Why doesn't it work under services.exe?